# Facing memory.limit while deploying Kimai open source?

Tags: php

[image]

While Deploying Kimai TimeTrack ,We are facing this above issuses

For PDF export the following requirement must be met:
Allowed memory usage should be at least 20MB
See memory_limit in php.ini file

Comment: "At least PHP version 5.4" didn't bother you?

Comment: I am using 5.6.20 PHP Product Version.

Comment: Ok, and what is your question exactly?

Comment: I went to php.ini file and added memory_limit = 512M,but its showing the same error while deploying.

Comment: Make sure you get the correct php.ini (not the one for php-cli) and restart your server after making changes to php.ini

Comment: ok i will check with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162897/discussion-between-vinay-guru-and-kerbholz).